# Import Access data into SQL Server CE (.mdb to .sdf)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I've found a few articles & discussions on how to import data from Access to SQL Server or SQL Server Express, but not to SQL Server CE.  I can access both the the Access data and CE data in the VS database explorer with seperate connections, but don't know how to move the data from one to the other.  (I'm using c#.)  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [PrimeWorks' DataPort Wizard](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortWizard.html).

Comment: I'd echo ctacke's answer.  There's not an easy point-and-click way of doing it with Visual Studio.  If you don't want to use PrimeWorks, the answer is too deep to discuss here. As Christopher Edwards pointed out, SSIS can do it, but learning that is an undertaking.

Comment: DataPort Wizard is the worst piece of software that i have ever come across. I got an exception saying "No exception from server" and thats is.

Comment: @Christo: checking with the authors of the software is probably better than complaining here.  They have a much better ability to do something about the problem than us.

Comment: i disagree tacke, people like myself will download the software based on your answer above. where you have made the recommendation, i have made mine. dont bother and write your own routine.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services), or even in SQL Server Explorer if you are not looking to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the the "sql server migration wizard" to convert it to sql server database and the use this [tool](http://www.johnnycantcode.com/post/UPDATE-SQL-Compact-Copy-Utility.aspx) to convert it back to a .sdf database