# How to update and use .mdb database access with Smart Device Application c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, windows-mobile

I am using VisualStudio2008, I created a Smart Device Project; and i would like to create an application to update something to an access database. For example something similar to a Windows application:

```
string connection = Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1};
string password = "123456";
string path = @"C:\mydb.mdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(connection, path, password));
```

There is the possibility of using the access database (.mdb) with Windows Mobile 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no support for Access databases in Windows Mobile. You would have to either use [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) or connect to an external database over the internet.

Comment: So, i should download SQL Server CE and use it in my project? There is a tutorial that explain exactly how "convert" and use the .mdb database ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a working solution. I recommend you go for an external database if you have access to a server. The question about migration from Access to SQL Server CE has already been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481719/import-access-data-into-sql-server-ce-mdb-to-sdf